# angularjs sitemap SEO

Tags: angularjs, seo, sitemap

I don't see any updated answer on similar topics (hopefully something has changed with last crawl releases), that's why I come up with a specific question.

I have an AngularJS website, which lists products that can be added or removed (the links are clearly updated). URLs have the following format:

```
http://example.com/#/product/564b9fd3010000bf091e0bf7/published
http://example.com/#/product/6937219vfeg9920gd903bg03/published
```

The product's ID (6937219vfeg9920gd903bg03) is retrieved by our back-end.
My problem is that Google doesn't list them, probably because I don't have a sitemap.xml file in my server..
In a day a page can be added (therefore a new url to add) or removed..
How can I manage this?
Do I have to manually (or by batch) edit the file each time?
Is there a smart way to tell Google: "Hey my friend, look at this page"?!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can create a JavaScript - AngularJS sitemap, and according to this guidance from google :
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

They Will crawl it.
you can also use [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) To validate that the pages rendered correctly
.
There is another study about google execution of JavaScript, 
http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157